# Get the longest route traveled in a graph

Tags: java, algorithm, graph, tree, graph-algorithm

I have an array of nodes that are connected to each other

I have below network of nodes. Here 0 is the starting point, I want to travel as many nodes as possible with a node traveled only once.
Also during a trip from 0 to destination node, I want to have only a single odd numbered node (like 1, 3, 5, 7).
Now I need to find out the longest route I can travel from my beginning position 0.

Example :

```
int[] array = { 0, 9, 0, 2, 6, 8, 0, 8, 3, 0 };
```

[image]

In above graph, below are possibilities:

```
0 -> 6 -> 4 (valid path, length = 3 nodes)
0 -> 9 -> 1 (Not valid path, length as we have 2 odd numbers here 1 & 9)
0 -> 2 -> 3 -> 8 (valid path, length = 4 nodes)
0 -> 2 -> 3 -> 8 -> 5 (Not valid path as we have 2 odd numbers here 3 & 5)
0 -> 2 -> 3 -> 8 -> 7 (Not valid path as we have 2 odd numbers here 3 & 7)

So the answer is 4 for this input.
```

Below is the program I am trying.

```
public int process(int[] array) {
    int count = array.length;
    ArrayList<Integer>[] branches = new ArrayList[count];
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        branches[i] = new ArrayList<>();
    }
    int begin = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        if (array[i] != i) {
            branches[i].add(array[i]);
            branches[array[i]].add(i);
        }
    }

    Arrays.stream(branches).forEach(System.out::println);

    Queue<Network> networkQueue = new LinkedList<Network>();
    ArrayList<Integer> networkList = branches[begin];
    networkList.forEach(value -> {
        Network net = new Network(0, value);
        networkQueue.add(net);
    });

    System.out.println("printing starting nodes.......");
    List<Network> nodes = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Network n : networkQueue) {
        nodes.add(n);
        System.out.println(n.value + " : " + n.road);
    }

    int result = 0;
    return result;
}

class Network {
    int road, value;

    public Network(int road, int value) {
        this.road = road;
        this.value= value;
    }

}
```

The program prints the branches and the nodes for the starting point i.e 0 :

```
[2, 6, 9]
[9]
[0, 3]
[2, 8]
[6]
[8]
[4, 0]
[8]
[5, 7, 3]
[1, 0]
printing starting nodes.......
2 : 0
6 : 0
9 : 0
```

I got stuck on finding the longest route, how to proceed next with this program, please help me here.

Comment: Are circular paths allowed, e.g. could 2 and 4 be connected, creating circle `0 -> 6 -> 4 -> 2 -> 0` ?

Comment: @Andreas, no nodes are not bi-directional, so circular is not allowed in my case.

Comment: 1) I think you meant to say that *edges* are not bi-directional (*undirected*). --- 2) Nothing in your question indicates that your graph is directed. The image is actually indicating an undirected graph, given the lack of arrows specifying directions. --- 3) Even with directed edges, a circular route can be defined, so you didn't really answer my question.

Comment: @Andreas, basically, i want to say is this is not possible:`0 -> 6 -> 4 -> 2 -> 0`

Comment: @Andreas, can you please help me in solving this problem

Comment: Short question for clarification do you really need the solution for a graph? Or is you problem restriticted to trees (as shown in your example)? From your comment about direction I gather that there might not be a path from every node to every other node. You also said that circular pathes are not possible. Does that restrict the path to be found or is it a basic constraint of how your graph is formed?

Comment: @second, I do not have much knowledge about graphs and trees so cannot comment on that. From starting point `0` I can travel to another nodes `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9`.

Answer (score 6):

This is a classic Depth First Search with backtracking problem.

The gist of this algorithm is as follow.
Starting from the start node, visit all its neighbors that have not been visited and do not break the max odd number node of 1 restriction. Add the current node to the current path and increment odd number node counter if the current node number is odd. Do this recursively until you've exhausted all valid paths for one neighbor, then backtrack for the remaining neighbors.

The following is the implementation with your provided input as the test case. I also added another list of list variable that is called res. This will give you all the valid longest path. I used a map to represent a graph, but you can modify this as you like.

```
import java.util.*;

public class LongestRoute {
    private static int maxLen = 0;
    private static List<List<Integer>> res = new ArrayList<>();

    public static int longestRouteWithRestrictions(Map<Integer, List<Integer>> graph, int startNode) {
        Set<Integer> visited = new HashSet<>();
        visited.add(startNode);
        List<Integer> path = new ArrayList<>();
        path.add(startNode);

        dfs(graph, startNode, visited, startNode % 2 == 1 ? 1 : 0, path);
        return maxLen;
    }

    private static void dfs(Map<Integer, List<Integer>> graph, int currentNode, Set<Integer> visited, int oddNumNodeCnt, List<Integer> path) {
        if(path.size() > maxLen) {
            maxLen = path.size();
            res.clear();
            res.add(new ArrayList<>(path));
        }
        else if(path.size() == maxLen) {
            res.add(new ArrayList<>(path));
        }
        for(int neighbor : graph.get(currentNode)) {
            if(visited.contains(neighbor) || oddNumNodeCnt == 1 && neighbor % 2 != 0) {
                continue;
            }
            path.add(neighbor);
            visited.add(neighbor);
            dfs(graph, neighbor, visited, oddNumNodeCnt + (neighbor % 2 != 0 ? 1 : 0), path);
            path.remove(path.size() - 1);
            visited.remove(neighbor);
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Init a test graph
        Map<Integer, List<Integer>> graph = new HashMap<>();
        Integer[] neighbors_0 = {2,6,9};
        List<Integer> list0 = Arrays.asList(neighbors_0);
        graph.put(0, list0);

        Integer[] neighbors_1 = {9};
        List<Integer> list1 = Arrays.asList(neighbors_1);
        graph.put(1, list1);

        Integer[] neighbors_2 = {0,3};
        List<Integer> list2 = Arrays.asList(neighbors_2);
        graph.put(2, list2);

        Integer[] neighbors_3 = {2,8};
        List<Integer> list3 = Arrays.asList(neighbors_3);
        graph.put(3, list3);

        Integer[] neighbors_4 = {6};
        List<Integer> list4 = Arrays.asList(neighbors_4);
        graph.put(4, list4);

        Integer[] neighbors_5 = {8};
        List<Integer> list5 = Arrays.asList(neighbors_5);
        graph.put(5, list5);

        Integer[] neighbors_6 = {0,4};
        List<Integer> list6 = Arrays.asList(neighbors_6);
        graph.put(6, list6);

        Integer[] neighbors_7 = {8};
        List<Integer> list7 = Arrays.asList(neighbors_7);
        graph.put(7, list7);

        Integer[] neighbors_8 = {5,7};
        List<Integer> list8 = Arrays.asList(neighbors_8);
        graph.put(8, list8);

        Integer[] neighbors_9 = {0,1};
        List<Integer> list9 = Arrays.asList(neighbors_9);
        graph.put(9, list9);

        System.out.println(longestRouteWithRestrictions(graph, 0));
        for(List<Integer> route : res) {
            System.out.println(route.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure that this is correct. The problem is that there might be multiple paths to a node - some through odd node, some shorter without that. If there exists an outgoing long path from that intermediate node through an odd node and you first visited the intermediate node through the odd-node path it seems you will miss that. One solution is to have visited as a pair of node and oddNumCodeCnt.

Comment: This won't miss the case you mentioned. The traversal only stops when it hit the 2nd  odd numbered node. The backtracking technique ensures that you'll explore both scenarios. If this intermediate node itself is odd numbered, a path that already has another odd numbered node ends here. If this intermediate node itself is even numbered, then the algorithm will keep exploring its unvisited neighbors.

Answer (score 3):

I'm sorry I don't have time to code it, but here is the logic i would apply.

1. starting from 0 the program generate linked lists of neighbors. In our case:

   ```
   [0->2]
   [0->9]
   [0->6]
   ```
2. checking neighbors (last elements in lists): if they are odd then increment a counter that refer to that path list.
   If the odd counter ==2 then erase that list from further analsys
3. for each list start again from 1. using last element as input. When no more VALID lists can be generated find the one with longest path, counting elements.

Just pay attention that a valid neighbor cannot be the same as the previous element in the list to avoid infinite loops: The only valid list generable by `[0->2]` it's `[0->2->3]`, and not `[0->2->0]`

Comment: I had the same idea, but I got stuck on how to implement that in my program.

Comment: You should start creating a list of linked list, so you can add and remove elements(linked list) easily. So just push into a linked list with only the node start. To semplify everything the Node class should have a list of neighbors, that contains the neighbors Nodes. Using that make the step 1. should not be that difficult. In the same way should not be difficult make checks on step 2. As condition to stop the loop in step 3. you can use a validation like: "until in each list the only neighbor of last node is the previous node" or saying in other words "until the node reached is a leaf" .

Answer (score 0):

You can try below approach, which should be relatively simple to implement as well as track. Firstly, you need to form a `Node` class which would have information about 3 things:

1. Max length of the path traveled so far while visiting all the nodes until this node from node 0, visiting each node just once.
2. A variable called `oddCounter` that counts the number of odd nodes encountered so far in this path.
3. A boolean variable `isVisited` to know if this node is already visited or not.

Now just implement `BFS` with nodes being as instance of this type of class defined above and while doing BFS, you just need to update each node variables accordingly.

Please note that you need to do BFS to all nodes starting from node 0, each time resetting the values of above 3 variables so you can keep track of the further paths in that route through this node. You can terminate the loop beyond certain nodes if you have already found one odd node. This way it would be more flexible in future as well where you might want to include maybe 2 or 3 odd numbered nodes in your path as compared to just one node currently.

Also, you would need to create a `resultList` and `currList` where you create a new `currList` everytime you traverse to a new node and update `resultList` with `currList` if length of `currList` is greater than the length of `resultList` as per the constraints we have.

I am sure that this approach can be optimized further using Dynamic Programming. As you know the route length and number of odd nodes until a given node say `i`, you can just do a BFS now from `ith` node and using `memoization` to keep track of previous route length and odd numbered nodes, which we are already tracking using above class we created.

Answer (score 0):

this is in c++, but i think it works the same:

```
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
void dfs(vector<vector<int>> &graphs, int nextidx, int& ticket, int& cities);

int solution(vector<int>& T)
{
    if (T.empty()) return 0;

    vector<vector<int>> graphs(T.size());

    int ticket = 1;
    int citiesmax = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < T.size(); ++i) {
        graphs[T[i]].emplace_back(i);
    }

    //    0-> 2, 6, 9
    //    1-> _
    //    2-> 3
    //    3-> 8
    //    4-> _
    //    5-> _
    //    6-> 4
    //    7-> _
    //    8-> 5, 7
    //    9-> 1

    
    for (int i = 0; i < graphs[0].size(); ++i)
    {
        int nextidx = graphs[0][i];
        int cities = 1;
        dfs(graphs, nextidx, ticket, cities);
        if(cities > citiesmax)
        {
            citiesmax = cities;
        }
    }
    
    return citiesmax;

}

void dfs(vector<vector<int>> &graphs, int nextidx, int &ticket, int& cities)
{
    if (graphs[nextidx].empty()) return;


    for (int i = 0; i < graphs[nextidx].size(); ++i)
    {
        if (graphs[nextidx][i] % 2 > 0)
        {
            if (ticket == 0) return;
            ticket--;       
        }
        int idx = graphs[nextidx][i];
        cities++;
        dfs(graphs, idx, ticket, cities);
    }
    return;
}


int main()
{
    vector<int> test1 = {0,9,0,2,6,8,0,8,3,0};


    int res = solution(test1);
    
}
```